# Can I submit an app built with Ratchet to the app store and google play store?

Tags: android, ios, html, ratchet-bootstrap, ratchet-2

I've found [Ratchet](http://goratchet.com/) from twitter. It's a HTML5 Framework to build mobile apps.

Is it possible to submit an app built with ratchet to the apple app store and google play store?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) to compile your web app into native Android, iOS and Windows Phone applications for submission to App Store and Google Play Store.

The process is extremely simple using their build process.

Comment: Cool, once you do can you accept my answer please :)

Answer (score 1):

As Ratchet builds HTML5 apps, not native apps, you cannot submit them directly to the Apple App Store. Only apps that use compiled code can be signed and submitted for approval and distribution via the App Store.

In theory you could build a native app that uses a UIWebView to present the HTML5 content.

It seems that you can submit HTML5 apps to the Google Play store, but there is still a packaging process - 
http://developer.streamezzo.com/tools/develop-test-and-publish-android